# Bash script breaks out of loop without sending the mail

Tags: bash, email, curl

I have a small snippet in bash

```
retries = 3 

for (( i=0; i<retries; i++)); do
    curl -1 --cipher ALL --connect-timeout 90 -T $zip_name ftps://ftp.box.com/Backup/$zip_name --user service.box.kto@crab.com:§fHyFSDF$o6
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && break
    echo "something went wrong, let's wait 6 seconds and retry"
    sleep 6
done

[[ $retries -eq i ]] && { echo "This email is a notification of Failure" | mail -s "Failed" "admin.box@text.com"  ; exit 1; }
```

The above loop should retry 3 times if there is a error doing curl, so if a curl error comes up it should mail to the email. But to test it out i revoked the access of the user, so i expected a email but this didn't work and i received following on console:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
```

Why is the code breaking in the first attempt if access if revoked from uploading the server

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting

Comment: @hek2mgl can you elaborate what you wanna say ?

Comment: I said that you need to quote (a) variables and (b) strings which contain special characters. I see no quotes in your code.

Comment: ok i get it.. but even if i apply the code, it should retry 3 times and then mail coz it couldn't upload the content.. why is that not happening

Answer (score 0):

```
retries = 3 

for (( i=0; i<$retries; i++))
do
    curl -1 --cipher ALL --connect-timeout 90 -T $zip_name 
ftps://ftp.box.com/Backup/$zip_name --user service.box.kto@crab.com:§fHyFSDF$o6
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]  
    then        
        break
        echo "something went wrong, let's wait 6 seconds and retry"
        sleep 6
    fi
done

if [[ $retries -eq $i ]] 
then
     echo "This email is a notification of Failure" | mail -s "Failed" "admin.box@text.com"
     exit 1
fi
```

You are better off using if syntax I think and I've noticed that you are not referring to the retries variable correctly. i.e. with $retries as opposed to retries and $i instead of i

Comment: I tried your changes as well.. the error remains exactly same. Why is curl breaking and not going for if ??

Comment: If the curl command is successful the first time, the loop would break out but the email wouldn't get sent as retries would only be 0?

Comment: yes exactly. and if the retires are attempted then after the 4th retry it should breakout and then send email

Comment: Run the script with bash -x and track your variables